# How to deploy ASP.NET Core app to Apache on macOS?

Tags: macos, apache, asp.net-core

I'm running the Visual Studio for Mac (Preview) 17.4, and I've built a new ASP.NET Core app (Razor). It runs on my desktop Mac's localhost fine via `Debug > Start Debugging`. Cool.

Now I'd like to deploy it to another macOS server, on which I've installed the .NET 6.04 SDK, which includes both the Runtime and the ASP.NET Core runtimes, from here:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

On this Mac server I've also installed Apache (using Homebrew), which has a working test HTML website serving from here:

```
/usr/local/var/www
```

Visual Studio has a `Build > Publish to Folder` option, which currently dumps all its files to a local folder on my dev machine:

```
[local project folder]/bin/Release/net6.0/publish
```

...it contains DLLs, .JSON, a UNIX executable, a `wwwroot` folder of static content, and a `runtimes` folder. I don't see any pages (in VS my web app is comprised of `.cshtml` pages)

So my question is, can someone explain where the binaries go in my target Apache site folder to properly serve this Razor project? Or share any guides on how to get the VS-published output running within Apache on the Mac server? I've copied the files over into the Apache website folder, but haven't been able to serve anything correctly. I found some guides for Linux but not specifically Apache on macOS. I come from a Windows background so don't know a whole lot about Apache on macOS, which is why I'm trying to get this dev site running on it.

Thanks

Comment: There are quite few guides about deploy .net application within Apache on the Mac server, but I used to use Nginx to get it done, try it if you can. Great day.

Comment: I have searched for them and couldn't find a relevant one. Can you explain where the build output binaries go in the macOS Apache site folder, or share a good link? Nginx sounds like a competing server to Apache, and I'm trying to use Apache on macOS.

Comment: Basically you want to [configure appache as a proxy server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-a-proxy-server) to the application. There is not such concept, as Apache could run it on its own. The application itself should run on its own via the integrated kestrel webserver. This should be [configured as a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-the-service-file). This is for Linux, but I am pretty sure, the concepts are the same to IOS

Answer (score 2):

1. In Visual Studio, go to Build > Publish to Folder and choose a local folder to publish to.
2. On your Apache server, install the .NET 6.04 SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0. This will include the Runtime and the ASP.NET Core runtimes.
3. Copy the contents of the publish folder from step 1 into the Apache website folder.
4. Edit the Apache configuration file to add a virtual host for your ASP.NET Core site.
5. Restart Apache.
6. Your ASP.NET Core site should now be accessible at the virtual host URL you configured.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like step 4 is what is needed next. I'll search for an article on how to edit the Apache configuration file to add a virtual host for my ASP.NET Core site.

Comment: Per http://smartwebdeveloper.com/mac/httpd-conf-location-mac the location for config files in macOS Apache is `etc/apache2`. MS has an article for configuring ASP.NET Core for Linux Apache (not macOS): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-a-proxy-server which suggests you create a new "myapp.conf" and add it to that folder. Seems like next you need to create a new myapp.service

Comment: Says thats to help Apache "manage the Kestrel process", whatever that is. Will mess w/ that next, modifying for macOS Apache where necessary. Pretty complicated, wish there was a guide for this. Maybe if I get it working I'll create one!

Comment: were you able to make it working @mdelvecchio ?